# Delta lake RESTORE issue (Databricks)

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake

I am working on Azure databricks and created a delta table on  ADLS Gen2.

I have 4 versions of delta lake created already.

I am trying to restore to version number 2 with the following command.

```
%sql
RESTORE TABLE Sales TO VERSION AS OF 2
```

Could someone let me know why I am not able to restore to the older version?
The error as below happening now.

```
Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
extraneous input 'RESTORE' expecting {'(', 'CONVERT', 'COPY', 'OPTIMIZE', 'ADD', 'ALTER', 'ANALYZE', 'CACHE', 'CLEAR', 'COMMENT', 'COMMIT', 'CREATE', 'DELETE', 'DESC', 'DESCRIBE', 'DFS', 'DROP', 'EXPLAIN', 'EXPORT', 'FROM', 'GRANT', 'IMPORT', 'INSERT', 'LIST', 'LOAD', 'LOCK', 'MAP', 'MERGE', 'MSCK', 'REDUCE', 'REFRESH', 'REPLACE', 'RESET', 'REVOKE', 'ROLLBACK', 'SELECT', 'SET', 'SHOW', 'START', 'TABLE', 'TRUNCATE', 'UNCACHE', 'UNLOCK', 'UPDATE', 'USE', 'VALUES', 'WITH'}(line 1, pos 0)

== SQL ==
RESTORE TABLE Sales TO VERSION AS OF 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check that you're using the correct version of the Databricks Runtime.  Per [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/delta-restore.html) it's available since DBR 7.4 only, and not in the earlier versions.  I just checked on DBR 7.5, and it works just fine

If you're on the earlier versions of Databricks Runtime, then you can use [INSERT OVERWRITE](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-dml-insert-overwrite-table.html) statement with select of specific version of the table:

```sql
insert overwrite <table> SELECT * FROM <table> VERSION AS OF <version>
```

Or another possibility is to use [TRUNCATE TABLE](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-truncate-table.html) + [INSERT INTO](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-dml-insert-into.html):

```sql
truncate table <table>;
INSERT INTO <table> SELECT * FROM <table> VERSION AS OF <version>
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex Ott.  My Databricks runtime version is 7.3 and I tried insert overwrite as you mentioned. It's throwing the following error for me 
Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Table default.Sales does not support dynamic overwrite in batch mode.;;

Comment: I had to delete table and then "INSERT INTO <table>  SELECT * from <table> VERSION AS OF 2" for restoration in the earlier version.

Comment: I just checked with DBR 7.3, and `insert overwrite` works just fine. But I updated answer with note about `truncate` + `insert into`.   Your problem is related to the support of dynamic partition overwrite in Delta: https://github.com/delta-io/delta/issues/348

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I just checked your updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for updating your solution and it works fine. How do I make overwrite work in DBR 7.3? Do I have to set up any parition checks while creating the table? Still dont understand why "insert overwrite" doesnt work for me.

Comment: that's related to the partitioning of the table - I linked the Github issue about it.  I suggest raising that to your solutions architect to fix it correctly...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.Tuncate + insert works and will be upgrading DBR soon.